# The set $S$ of complex numbers $z$ satisfying $|z| < 1$ or $| z − 3i | < 1$ is a domain. Is this statement true or false?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

The set $S$ of complex numbers z satisfying $|z| < 1$ or $| z − 3i | < 1$ is a domain.

I found this statement true but the book (Dennis G. Zill and Patrick D. Shanahan - A First Course in Complex Analysis with Applications (2003, Jones and Bartlett Publishers, Inc.) says it is false.

I tried to look at it in this way. Firstly, the $0$ centered open circle is a domain because it is open and connected. Secondly, the $0+3i$ centered ($(0,3)$ on complex plane) circle is also open and connected. I said this statement is true but the book says it is false, why?

Comment: Please include the author's definition of a "domain" (that word is less standard than one might otherwise expect). Also, please typeset all of the mathematics in your question using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference); as it stands, your question is a little hard to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $S$ is explicitly described as
\begin{equation}
S = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < 1 \text{ or } |z - 3i| < 1\}
 \end{equation}
which is open, but not connected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that the two disks described are open connected sets, but they are 1 unit apart so their union is (open but) not connected.

Comment: So we are taking or as union? I thought one or other (at least one)

Comment: "$z\in A$ or $z\in B$" means "$z\in A\cup B$"

Comment: Oh okay, i did a small translation mistake thank you so much. Have a good day.